# Authentication for website and mobile app

Tags: spring-boot, rest, web, mobile, jwt

I'm doing a Spring Boot application (Rest API, JPA, etc), used (via Rest) from a website (Angular) and from a mobile app (Android).

The user using the mobile app (in the future) will be able to authenticate via Facebook, Google, etc. I will store in the database some information received from the social networks necessary for the app.

I implemented the authentication by providing username and password (saved in the database) and by releasing an access token (JWT) from the backend, used by both front-ends on every REST request to Spring Boot.

Now I would like that, for the user's mobile app, you don't have to enter the username and password every time, and instead you remain logged in forever.

Reading on the internet I saw that it is possible to generate a "refresh token" that the app can use when the backend (Spring Boot) returns HTTP Error 401.
The app uses the refresh token to ask the backend for a new access token. If the refresh token has also expired then the user is forced to re-enter the username and password otherwise if it remains logged.

Which flow is correct and secure?

Thanks

Comment: consider posting opinion-based questions about security on https://security.stackexchange.com/. SO is more about resolving technical issues than about deciding on the correct security flow ;) that being said, a refresh token is what Google uses for their APIs. it's a tried and trusted pattern.

Comment: @PaulBenn i wrote on https://security.stackexchange.com/. Do you think JWT is the best way or not?

Comment: I think it's an acceptable way. No one on SO can give a judgement on whether it is the "best" way without the full context, sorry! hope the guys over at Security SE have more information.